# Paragraph motions in single-line buffer

Tags: cursor-motions, object-motions

[This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29399) looks at how paragraph motions behave when the buffer consists of only two lines. But what if the buffer has just one line?

Both <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> move the cursor to the last character of the line, regardless of its original position. Both <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> delete text from under the cursor to the end of the line. Similar statements can be made about <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd> combined with either paragraph motion. How should this behavior be understood?

Comment: The expected behavior is described in @Mass's quote from the POSIX standard: `{` should move the cursor to the first non-blank character or the BOL and `}` should move the cursor to the last non-blank character or the EOL. Therefore, the current behavior should be understood as a bug and reported as such.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exaclty is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: 1. `$ vim --clean`. 2. Insert one line of gibberish and leave insert mode. 3. Where is the cursor after `}`? 4. Where is the cursor after `{`? 5. Did you expect the answer to #4? OP doesn't. I don't.

Comment: sounds like a bug. Please create a ticket for it. Similar wrong behaviour is with using `]]`.

Comment: @photon_engine here's your chance to contribute something to Vim :-D

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt One could argue the behavior of `]]` is expected: in a multiline buffer with empty `'filetype'`, `]]` jumps to the beginning of the last line, so in the degenerate case of a single-line buffer, `]]` should also jump to the beginning of the only line

Comment: @romainl I can't say I fully understood the POSIX standard and how Vim chooses to break from it, but thanks for confirming that this behavior is indeed unexpected; I have filed a bug report: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13780

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: fixed as of https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v9.0.2188